# restful query to search on directory.io

Tags: rest, get

I'm trying to use the query restful on the site directory.io to go back to a certain address

Can you give me some advice because with GET and any key and value always returns me the first page

Comment: Please show example(s) of what you have tried.

Comment: i've tried a GET q={address} but he return in first page. I've also tried a GET with q={key} but nothing. WIth url nothing

Comment: If it is truly RESTful, the first page should return hyperlinks, which you can follow.

Comment: you have view the site?

Comment: if anyone look the site give me a help. Q: Is there a RESTful API?
A: Yes.

   Method  Resource                                          Description                  Media Type
   ------  --------                                          -----------                  ----------
   GET     /:page_no                                         Fetches a page               text/html
   GET     /warning:understand-how-this-works!/:private_key  Finds a page by private key  text/html. I deduct is rest but is the only api have the website?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading this http://directory.io/faq

You may then find you don't wish to use the 'api'

> Q: Should I search by private key?
>   A: No. I log and steal everything.